# Searching with each character CoreData using NSFetchedResultsController is very slow with large number of records

Tags: ios, search, core-data

I'm having a pre-loaded database of 20000 records.

Basically there are two entities in which searching is done, `City Entity` and Other one is `street Entity`. City has "Name" attribute and `Street Entity` has name attribute too, both `city and street` are in `one-to-many relationship`. As a city can have many streets.

Now when a user can search with any character like "a or b" anything and it should so show user the respective city and or street.Eveytime i have to reload and reconfigure NSFetchedResultsController.

I have implemented a `NSPredicate` to filter out records.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"(name CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (SELF.streets.name CONTAINS[c] %@)",text,text)
 predicateArray.append(predicate)
```

This predicate is used for filtering the records.I'm also using MagicalRecord a wrapper over coreData.The searching used to be very as i'm searching for every character.

Any help would be very greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is your search a contains instead of begins with? Why allow searching by a single letter? Have you run the search on a background thread? Have you added logic to prevent searches running if the user continues typing? It seems like you're creating something and worrying about a problem that most people wouldn't have...

Comment: I have a requirement for using contains keyword and also for single letter searching.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to do filter in memory 20000 rows. It's super fast! No lag at all. It seems that you are going to the persistent store more than once and this is what I suggest:

- Stop using `NSFetchedResultController` (before doing that try the third point it could work)
- Create two `NSFetchRequest`: one of them will give you Cities and the other will give you the streets. So you will get an array of cities and array of streets.
  This approach will help you avoid fetching over the relationship `city.streets` which is very inefficient. Better if you could combine and map the two to a single array of Strings.
- **Very important:** Set the `request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false`. Otherwise you will keep going to the DB to get the city.name or street.name.

When a search textfield changes:

- Filter first the cities then the streets.
- Reload  the `tableView`

**EDIT: Test Example** 
I tested the code below

- iPhone 6: between 100ms-170ms for the first character. Then it becomes faster. (2x) I din't feel any lag.
- iPad mini 2: between 300ms-350ms for the first character. Then it becomes faster. (2x) There was some lag.

  ```
  class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

  var streets = [Street]()
  var cities = [City]()

  var filteredStreets: [Street] = []
  var filteredCities: [City] = []

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      cities = findAllCities()
      streets = findAllStreets()
      filteredCities = cities
      filteredStreets = streets
  }

  func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
      filterItemsWithCurrentSearchText(searchText)
  }

  func filterItemsWithCurrentSearchText(text: String){
      if text.isEmpty {
          filteredStreets = streets
          filteredCities = cities
      } else {
          NSLog("1")
          filteredStreets = streets.filter{ $0.name.rangeOfString(text, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil }
          NSLog("2")
          filteredCities = cities.filter{ $0.name.rangeOfString(text, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil }
          NSLog("3")
      }
      tableView.reloadData()
      NSLog("4")
  }


  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return filteredStreets.count + filteredCities.count
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")!

      if indexPath.row < filteredCities.count{
          cell.textLabel!.text = "City:" + filteredCities[indexPath.row].name
      }else{
          cell.textLabel!.text = "Street:" + filteredStreets[indexPath.row-filteredCities.count].name
      }
      return cell
  }

  func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      return 1
  }

  func findAllCities() -> [City]{
      let request = City.MR_createFetchRequest()
      request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
      return City.MR_executeFetchRequest(request) as! [City]
  }

  func findAllStreets() -> [Street]{
      let request = Street.MR_createFetchRequest()
      request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
      return Street.MR_executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Street]
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: Fine I would fetch cities and streets seperately but i have to cities on the list second fetch would  return streets, then either i would have to again fetch cities from the streets, therefore again a time taking task.

Comment: Also i tried fetch  seperately but still its very slow atleast 1.5 seconds.

Comment: can you share the code? Did you put returnsObjectAsFaults when you fetched the street and cities separately?

Comment: If the code is still unacceptable we can try to optimize the filterItemsWithCurrentSearchText method

Comment: Can we go in chat room.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128029/discussion-between-elka-and-user1068810).

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working with such a large database it'll probably be a good idea to index the database.

This should increase the speed of searches as you'll be just looking through the index for matches rather than having to look at all 20,000 records in the database each time. Think of this as looking up something in a book's index rather than having to read each page to find what you're looking for.

[Database indexing - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index)

Core Data in iOS has indexing built in. Try enabling it on the attributes that you want to be indexed and see if that helps speed up your search times.

[image: Core Data attribute indexing]

Comment: Simo thanks for your quick feedback, i have indexed the attribute but still its takes 4-5 seconds to show the data. As there's also one-to-many relationship between cities and streets which takes lot of time in searching.

Comment: In that case you should look into optimising your fetch request. There are some good areas covered here: https://artandlogic.com/2013/01/optimizing-core-data-searches-and-sorts/

Comment: Still the searching is slow.

Comment: The indexing won't work. You are searching for a string with CONTAINS. So  the query should pass over all the items for the match. Have you tried to load the data and filter in memory? Sometimes it could be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use the following options to increase the speed of fetching.

In your case the following may help to retrieve faster results,

- **fetchBatchSize** : Setting a batch size limits the amount of data that is retrieved from the data store at a time. If the batch size were set to 20 for a result set of 1,000, then the result array would be populated only up to 20. When we iterate past 20, the next batch will be retrieved.

The following may be used if in case you needed

- **fetchLimit:** : Sometimes we only want a specific amount of objects returned. This is useful when there are a lot of objects. The UI won’t be updated until the fetch is complete so limiting the fetch is necessary.

For detailed reference : [CoreData](http://www.learncoredata.com/how-to-fetch-data/)